# How to delete members from ASp.NET membership database on gridview selected item?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a list of registered users in gridview...

I want when i click on delete button on selected item in gridview, then the record of user will be deleted from the whole database... on single delete command of sqldatasource in gridview....

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DeleteCommand from the grid and specify the parameter:

```
DeleteCommand ="DELETE FROM TBL WHERE ID=@id"

<DeleteParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
</DeleteParameters>
```